# Unexpected number printed for CLLocation.coordinate.latitude

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have an NSLog statement in my `-didUpdateToLocation` method which prints the latitude of my location as expected:

```
NSLog(@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
```

prints `37.3317`

In the same method, i assign `newLocation` to a CLLocation instance variable for use elsewhere.

`self.selectedLocation = newLocation;`

But when i NSLog this using `%g`, i get this value `-1.96638e-202`

`NSLog(@"%g", self.selectedLocation.coordinate.latitude);`

What i have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's `NSLog("%g", self.selectedLocation.coordinate.latitude)` not `NSLog(@"%g", self.selectedLocation.coordinate.latitude)`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - its @"%g"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the .h file, what do you have for the property?

That is, you have a line like:

@property (copy)CLLocation* newLocation;

what is in the parenthesis?

Comment: the property is (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: Well, so much for my one guess.  It doesn't seem likely, but since didUpdateLocation is asynchronos, something odd might be happening.  What if you change the assignment to 

select.selectedLocation = [ [CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude] 

I can't imagine why you'd have to, though

Comment: added a release to get rid of the potential leak

Comment: Well thats even stranger, i did as you suggested using `[[alloc]init...]`, when i print `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` in `didUpdateToLocation`, it works, then i do the assignment, then print `selectedLocation.coordinate.latitude`, and get another weird number `2.42797e-288`, which is different to the first weird number. Whats going on here? Is there a special format code needed for latitudes/longitudes? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i messed up too - when i print after the assignment, the value is correct, 37.3317. So its back to square one, printing self.selectedLocation.coordinate.latitude outside of the didUpdateToLocation method gives a weird number. I'm new to debugging in Xcode, so i'm a bit lost - thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yeah, XCode is a little user-hostile at first.  It gets easier.  

Anyway, just to confirm:

1. print newLocation - works
2. assign to instance variable using [[alloc] init] works in didUpdateToLocation ?
3. print instance variable outside of didUpdateToLocation -- doesn't work?  Am I understanding the sequence correctly?  Or are you printing the value of self.selectedLocation inside of didUpdateToLocation and it is showing the incorrect number?

Comment: No youre correct. That's the sequence and inside of didUpdateToLocation the instance variable is fine. Outside it prints incorrectly. The incorrect print appears on the console before the prints in didUpdateToLocation even though I am printing after calling [startUpdatingLocation]

Comment: Okay, you are sure that the assignment has happened before you print the instance variable, right?  There can be a considerable lag after calling startUpdatingLocation before didUpdateToLocation gets called.  

Can you confirm that your NSLogs appear in this order:

1. display newLocation
2. Assignment of newLocation to self.selectedLocation.
3. display self.selectedLocation

If they do, try adding retain to the end of the [ [ alloc ] init...]

Comment: The NSLogs appear in this order: 1: display self.selectedLocation (-1.96638e202) 2: display newLocation (37.3317) 3: after assignment of self.selectedLocation (37.3317). 2 & 3 are inside didUpdateToLocation.  It would appear that there is a lag then between startUpdatingLocation and didUpdateToLocation, but this still doesnt explain the -1.9 weirdness. This is all running in the simulator by the way. Should that affect anything? Cheers.

Comment: The only difference in the simulator and the device is that the simulator will always return Apples address.

Yes, there is a substantial lag between sending the startUpdatingLocation and the didUpdateToLocation (and it's greater on the device); the GPS has to start, and I think I've seen 10 seconds from a cold start until the first didUpdateToLocation (depending on all sorts of things, including location of wireless routers that can be used to determine the location, position of satellites, solar flares).  The weird number you are seeing is normal; it means selectedLocation is uninitialized.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but how then can I get a pause until I have a location update? Because after startUpdatingLocation (in viewDidLoad) I have a call to a webservice which is getting passed with the weird number. Obviously this is failing. Thanks.

Comment: Put a semaphor before the call to the website.  Have the mutex changed inside of didUpdateToLocation.  Block on the semaphor before calling the web site.

I have some sample code for this if you want it

Comment: Yes please that would be very helpful. What's a semaphore and mutex?

Comment: A semaphor is a flag that prevents 2 threads from accessing the same bit of data at the same time.  In ObjectiveC, the class is an NSLock class.

Basically, you want to this:

startUpdatingLocation, then waitUntilIhaveAValidLocation, then getWebPageWithThisLocation.  The object that would provide the waituntilIhaveavalidlocation functionality is a semaphor.  Unfortunately my code doesn't do what I thought it does. Give me a little bit and I'll dig something up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this in the simulator? If you are it will always return the latitude as "37.33" and longitude as "-122.0" or near around which is the location of Cupertino, California, USA(The apple headquarters).

So if this is not the case show us some your code snippet.

Hope I helped you.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: I know the sim always returns cupertino - the issue is the negative value to the e power i'm seeing when printing out the instance variable. thanks.